# What is the right initializer one should give to the tf.contrib.layers.convolution2d function in TensorFlow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I was reading the documentation for [making 2d convolutional layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/contrib.layers/higher_level_ops_for_building_neural_network_layers_#convolution2d) in tensorflow from the contrib section and was wondering what was the right or best way to initialize the weights when using the [tf.contrib.layers.convolution2d](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/contrib.layers/higher_level_ops_for_building_neural_network_layers_#convolution2d) function. Unfortunately they don't really say explicitly nor provide an example, so it was unclear to me what is the intended way to use this. The function has a `weights_initializer` parameter which can be set. I have tried setting it to both:

1. tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer
2. tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer_conv2d

neither seem to return an error and the first one seems to train fine (as far as I can tell). However, it would be awesome to check if this is the right way of using this contrib layer (or maybe since it seems to be a contrib function, how does one check the "official" source code maybe to see their docs or test cases or maybe address the my question in their gitissues, if appropriate).

Answer (score 2):

At the time of writing, tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer_conv2d is an alias for tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer (The source at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/initializers.py#L59 has a line that is literally xavier_initializer_conv2d = xavier_initializer) so it would be very surprising if one worked and the other did not :)

So, one is as good as the other (both are fine).